# Wix Toolset install optional component

Tags: wix3.10

I am trying to use Wix Toolset 3.10 to install a small app.  The thing I am having trouble with it getting it to launch a third-party .exe that is an optional feature.

Here is the related code in my Product.wxs file:

```
<Feature Id="iCalSetup" Title="Automation" Level="2">
  <ComponentRef Id="icalsetup"/>
</Feature>

<Component Id="icalsetup" Guid="*" Directory="PRODUCTFOLDER">
  <File Id="icalsetup" Name="foo.exe" Source="$(var.*****.TargetDir)foo.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
</Component>
```

I am wrapping the ending msi in a bootstrapper application. to generate a .exe.  The feature/selection tree shows the optional components correctly, but the .exe is never executed when it is selected.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish what I was looking to do.  The .exe I was using was a self-extracting executable.  I extracted it and created component groups for the extracted files.  then I put an MsiPackage in the Bootstrapper app.  if the component groups are not copied over, then the msi does not run.